# How to expose a web API to a google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google apps spreadsheet, and I want to write a script that can be accessed via any browser, will generate a response using data from the spreadsheet, and return it to the browser.

I put in a lot of data in the spreadsheet that is required for my app. I want to automate the process of getting the data from the spreadsheet and integrating into the app before creating a build. Right now I run the script manually, download the result, and copy it into the app's data folder.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact with your script via [HTTP Post](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

[doPost Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#doget_and_dopost)

Here is a little example of a doPost function

```
function doPost(e){

       return ContentService.createTextOutput(SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name).getDataRange().getValues())
}
```

Comment: Thanks, from within the doPost link, there was a link to web apps (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) which was very helpful.

I guess what I was missing was the how to deploy part